# How to replace without overwriting

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've got a list of words I'm using for writing a game:

```
words[0[0] = 'INCREDIBLE'
words[0[1] = 'SUPERB'
words[0[2] = 'SUBLIME'
words[0[3] = 'PHENOMENAL'
words[0[4] = 'BLITZKRIEG'

words[1[0] = 'EXCELLENT'
words[1[1] = 'BOFFO'
words[1[2] = 'SMASH'
words[1[3] = 'SUPREME'
words[1[4] = 'OUTSTANDING'
```

I want to make this into a 2d array by replacing the second '[' with ','

Obviously I can do this manually in no time at all.  Nevertheless it's something I'd very much like to learn how to do with regex and notepad++.  How would I identify the second '[' and then replace it without changing the adjoining numbers?

Currently I use \d+[\d+ to find it.

Answer (score 3):

Just use this:

Find what: `(\[\d+)\[`
Replace with: `$1,`

Comment: @Veta hower you should give the credits to Toto and not to yourself ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `(^words\[\d+)\[` by `$1,`

Comment: @NicolasAlbert Users with less than 20 rep points (or something like that) cannot vote (but Veta could accept this answer if he doesn't mark his own answer as accepted...). +1 from me then :)

Comment: You have to escape the first `[`

Answer (score 1):

If all or most `[` are are in the same column, you can also use <kbd>Alt</kbd> to select the whole column via mouse and just enter `'` to replace it in the whole marked range.

Answer (score 0):

I used lookbehind (?<=\d)[

Lookahead and lookbehind are two very neat (and seemingly necessary) regex features.

Comment: Be aware that will replace `word123[0[2]` with `word123,0[2]`